# how to open a html page in linux like opening in windows browser?

Tags: python, linux, selenium

I have one html page whose name is temp.html, and it likes:

```
<div class="file_div1" style="border-top:none; margin-top:0">
    <div class="file_div1_1">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var file_id=1001;
        </script>
        <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' src='http://files.testjs.com/cs/jsfile/js/f.js'></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

these html fragments would triggle a http request whoes url like:

```
http://ff.test.com/rf?id=1001
```

I change the hosts file in win7 and make “ff.test.com” to redirect to 10.1.120.81(this is my offline linux machine), and then I open this html page by using python + selenium in firefox, the http request would send to 10.1.120.81.

however, it is very slow by using python + selenium, if I want to do this in linux, what should I do?

I try to use urllib2 in python or wget command in my offline linux machine, unfortunately, the http request could send to 10.1.120.81, and I only get the static html page, but could not **execute** it.

is there any other methods? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I'm not clear what you mean.  Are you in the windowing environment (X11)? Or just command line?

If you want to execute an html file so the javascript will run, for example, you would use something that mimics a web browser; lynx, or even curl?

I think.  I don't really understand the question, but maybe this helps!

Comment: thank you. in windows, it works well, the html file would be executed in the firefox and send the http request. however I could only get the static html file in linux, I could not execute it. any suggestions?

Comment: how to use firefox in linux? sorry, I didnot use it before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) library that is part of Python? It is OS independent as well.

Comment: thank you, I have tried it. and I could only get the static html page, could not execute it.

Comment: Is your question regarding how to change `hosts` in Linux box like you did on Windows?

Comment: I have change the hosts(/etc/hosts)， but I could not open the html: firefox http://inte.test.com/test.html.